# User Password Expiry date is null in user_users?

Tags: oracle, metadata

Is it possible to find my password expiry date without asking the DBA?

My user does not have privileges to view the `DBA_USERS` table. Also, I tried `select * from USER_USERS` table, but `expiry_date` is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be that your account has been assigned the profile with [`PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm#DBSEG567) set to `UNLIMITED`, and thus your password will never expire. You can query the [USER_PASSWORD_LIMITS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5384.htm#REFRN26161) view to determine what password limits are currently in effect for your account:

```
SQL> select * from user_password_limits;

RESOURCE_NAME                    LIMIT
-------------------------------- ---------
FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS            10
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME               UNLIMITED
PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME              UNLIMITED
PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX               UNLIMITED
PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         NULL
PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME               1
PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME              7
```

Comment: See also [Using Data Dictionary Views to Find Information About Users and Profiles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/users.htm#DBSEG20026).

Answer (score 1):

```
select username, account_status, expiry_date from user_users;
```

works for me. Caveat: this works only for the user you are logged on as.

Answer (score 0):

You need elevated privileges to view DBA_USERS - that's if you can't select from DBA_USERS.
Get help from a DBA or use an account with the required privileges.

Answer (score -3):

Issue this command:

```
select username, account_status, expiry_date, profile from dba_users;
```

Comment: The question states: `"My user does not have privileges to view the DBA_USERS table"`.